# 'Cow point': is this an idiomatic term for a fielding position in cricket, thinking in particular of on the Subcontinent?

Tags: cricket, terminology

I've just been watching a T-20 match played in the Subcontinent, and a field position was referred to as 'cow point'. 'Cow corner' is standard nowadays, but this seemed to be in the deep backward point - third man sector.

I've found no reference to 'cow point' in readily available online dictionaries, ELU or here. Is it a reasonably common term on the Subcontinent, and have I identified the position correctly?

Comment: Which level game was this, is there any videos or something to point out the term being used? As you said, I also didn't found any other reference apart from cow corner.

Comment: It was the 'European League', played, I think, in Spain(!) Virgin 553? Commentators from all over the place, but the expression, I believe, only used by those/one from the Subcontinent. / The term 'a Man U' also appeared: 7 off a no-ball (1 + 6), 7 with zero balls used up, to commemorate the recent Liverpool triumph. 'Maximo' and 'minimo' (5) also used.